# How to know if the elements of the lists from a dataframe column exist on a list on python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

i have a dataframe of ussers with their telephones, and some are repeated so i have a list with the repeated telephones and i want to obtain the index of the ussers that have a telephone that is included on that list.

The column of that dataframe have lists with the telephones like:

```
|Id | Name | Tlf                       |
|:- |:----:| -------------------------:|
| 0 |  A   | ['xxxxxxxxx','zzzzzzzzz'] |
| 1 |  B   | ['yyyyyyyyy']             |
| 2 |  C   | ['zzzzzzzzz','ooooooooo'] |
| 3 |  D   | None                      |
| 4 |  E   | ['xxxxxxxxx']             |
| 5 |  F   | None                      |
```

And I have a list of repeated telephones like:

```
tlf_r = [None, 'xxxxxxxxx', 'zzzzzzzzz']
```

So i want to take the index of the dataframe from the users with this repeated telephones to extract them to another csv.
I tried with:

```
df_[df_.Tlf.isin(tlf_r)][['Name','Tlf']].sort_values('Tlf').to_csv('C:/x/y/z/v/Repeated_Telephones.csv',sep=';')
```

But `df_.Tlf.isin(tlf_r)` search the lists from the column like `['xxxxxxxxx']` on the other list and never match.

Comment: `Tlf.isin(tlf_r)` doesn't work because `Tlf` is a list, not a string. You need to explode it and test each number.

Comment: The output of what you expect is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `explode` your lists then use `isin` to filter out your dataframe:

```
>>> df.explode('Tlf').loc[lambda x: x['Tlf'].isin(tlf_r)].sort_values('Tlf')

   Id Name        Tlf
0   0    A  xxxxxxxxx
4   4    E  xxxxxxxxx
0   0    A  zzzzzzzzz
2   2    C  zzzzzzzzz
3   3    D       None
5   5    F       None
```

If you want to keep rows where at least one value match to `tlf_r`, use:

```
>>> df.loc[df['Tlf'].explode().isin(tlf_r).groupby(level=0).max()]
   Id Name                     Tlf
0   0    A  [xxxxxxxxx, zzzzzzzzz]
2   2    C  [zzzzzzzzz, ooooooooo]
3   3    D                    None
4   4    E             [xxxxxxxxx]
5   5    F                    None
```